# Do I have to lock dependencies when locking Thunar at current version?

Tags: kde, dependencies, software-updates, plasma5, thunar

For the purpose of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1430542/925128) problem I have decided to lock Thunar to current version in Muon.

My goal is that Thunar stays as it is and its configuration files that it owns in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` are not changed by an update (`/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.FileManager.service` and
`/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.Thunar.FileManager1.service`).

I am on Kubuntu 22.04 / Plasma so that Thunar comes with a few dependencies. Is it possible that those dbus-services files are owned / controlled by such dependencies
and that they are updated while Thunar is not?

Comment: I wouldn't worry for dbus services as long as whatever new version of dbus makes many things become obsolete. I would more worry about Thunar dependencies. At some point in the future, you'll almost certainly reach a point where you'll be forced to block their updates as well. (without any prior advice from your package manager since dependencies are likely to be specified >= someversion.) => Carefully read the changelogs is the only good advice I learnt from my personal experience in locking packages to whatever particular version.

Comment: @MC68020 - so I should also lock all dependencies that came with Thunar? That makes sense. Could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A/ I would not worry that much about thunar's d-bus services.**

d-bus services are generally owned by the package they are associated to and should not be updated as long as the package itself is not updated.
This is valid for the two services you mentioned in OP.

**B/ I would be more worrying about the package's runtime dependencies.**

Because package managers often define packages' dependencies without specifying any version or specifying a minimum version, whenever you update your system, these dependencies will be updated without notice.
It might well happen (Well… it will happen) some day that some update just breaks your locked package.

And of course, because these dependencies also depend on other packages, themself depending on other packages… you realise that it would just be insensible to lock everything **a-priori** in the cascade… since you'll end up locking your entire system and, most of the dependencies, for no real reason.
So you must proceed with reason :

**When should you start worrying** : When the version of your locked package stops being supported by your distribution.
Renowned distributions do their best ensuring that the packages they support are not broken by whatever update. But from the time they drop their support, they logically no longer care.
From that point you should stop updating blindly and carefully read the changelogs of the (first level) dependencies prior to updating and eventually lock some update that would break your locked package.
Of course, from that point (of having blocked one first level dependency update) you'll need to watch its own dependencies (second level deps of your initially locked package) and treat them identically.
Of course you understand that it can (will) at some point be… a hard work. (*1)

**Getting deeper with regards to *thunar* specifically.**

You do not precisely tell which version of thunar you locked. On my distribution (gentoo) 4.16.11 current stable displays the following run time dependencies :

```
>=dev-libs/glib-2.50
>=x11-libs/gdk-pixbuf-2.14
>=x11-libs/gtk+-3.22:3
>=xfce-base/exo-4.15.3
>=xfce-base/libxfce4ui-4.15.3
>=xfce-base/libxfce4util-4.15.2
>=xfce-base/xfconf-4.12
>=media-libs/libexif-0.6.19
dev-libs/gobject-introspection
>=x11-libs/libnotify-0.7
>=dev-libs/libpcre-6
>=xfce-base/xfce4-panel-4.10
dev-libs/libgudev
>=dev-util/desktop-file-utils-0.20-r1
x11-misc/shared-mime-info
>=gnome-base/gvfs-1.18.3
virtual/udev
```

Since several of these dependencies are optional and your package version possibly different, I suggest you crosscheck with you actual implementation.
Moreover, the following is written in a complete unawareness of one particular point :
You write running kde-plasma for your desktop. Which afaik relies on QtDBus implementation when thunar-xfce relies on GDBus. How do these two different  implementations cohabitate I cannot tell… You'll be on your own to discover how and its implications in terms of dependencies.

For what concerns the above list, I would not worry in a near future about whatever… **xfce packages excepted**.
Of course gtk (I assume gtk3) support will be removed on some day but not in a near future.
However I know nothing of the xfce packages. And if I can compare to kde framework which evolve rather quickly and forces packages that depend on to upgrade at a same pace, these are the package I would worry about.

That said… IF (and only if) under your KDE-Plasma desktop, thunar is the only one package depending on xfce thingies… you won't loose whatever in locking those packages at once…

**To sum up with** : Yes ! If they are currently installed into your system, Do lock exo, libxfce4ui, libxfce4util, xfconf and xfce4-panel to their current release... d'better be safe than sorry. ;-)

---

(*1) The author of these lines blocked the updates of the nvidia proprietary drivers about 2 years ago. For long, I managed (with a bit of magic) to keep my system perfectly working on latest packages versions apart from half a dozen of low level packages locked.
Two years later… I must acknowledge being forced to lock 200 packages over my 1300 grand total.
No worry… everything works perfectly and if it works… don't fix it. But… this represents quite a lot of work.